# What am I: When things get serious, I'm upside-down

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, lateral-thinking

Here's a fun puzzle I came up with:

> I cannot walk, but I can swim.
>
> A liquid keeps me from being slim.
>
> Only few people can see my wave.
>
> I spend my nights in a kind of cave.
>
> I don’t breathe, yet cannot drown.
>
> When things get serious, I prefer upside-down.

What am I?

Comment: As a bonus, when it's solved I'll also post a German version if anyone's interested.

Comment: I don't think that'll work so well - we're an English-only site.

Comment: I'm completely aware of that, I'm just offering it as a bonus in case there's a German speaker on here who wants to use the puzzle in German.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are :

> A fetus

I cannot walk, but I can swim.

> fetus swimming in the womb.

A liquid keeps me from being slim.

> The placenta brings blood for the baby, which keeps the fetus from being slim.

Only few people can see my wave.

> Only  obgyn doctors (using USG equipment) can see me, and hear my heart wave.

I spend my nights in a kind of cave.

> The mother womb

I don’t breathe, yet cannot drown.

> A fetus does not breathe!

When things get serious, I prefer upside-down.

> Time to be born.

Comment: Very good, your answer is correct! I edited the part `A liquid keeps me from being slim` to name the appropriate liquid.

Comment: Does the Fetus really swim? It floats.

Comment: Actually, yes, as swimming is simply the act of moving in the water (floating doesn't technically constitute movement). It's also why babies are inherent "swimmers" when they're young, and can be taught to properly propel themselves in water soon after maturation. Lastly, +1 for referring to a fetus' "accommodations" as a cave....^_^

Comment: @SliderBlackrose There's little point in having people spoiler-tag their answer if you then reveal it in the comments ...

Comment: @Rubio The answer was submitted **and accepted**. Any reason to hide information later?

Comment: @SliderBlackrose The entire purpose of spoiler-tagging answers is so that other would-be solvers can try their hand at the puzzle without having the answer revealed until they themselves act to reveal it. Those other would-be solvers may be looking at a particular puzzle days, weeks, months or even years after it was originally posted and solved. So *yes*, there is absolutely a reason to preserve the mystery even after the puzzle had been solved and the correct answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> Fish in an Aquarium

I cannot walk, but I can swim

> The first line means that it is a living being which lives in water

A liquid keeps me from being slim

> The liquid is water

Only few people can see my wave

> Without tickets people can't enter the Aquarium.

I spend my nights in a kind of cave

> Since the Aquarium is closed at night it is similar to a Cave

I don’t breathe, yet cannot drown

> The fish can't drown

When things get serious, I prefer upside-down

> If the fish is sick for example (Swim Bladder Disorder) it swims upside down to get attention

Comment: It's much easier to gauge answers when the original lines are quoted instead of references to them above.

Comment: Will update the answer. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I feel like an

> "eye"

could also be a right answer.

**I cannot walk, but I can swim.**

> Eye in the fluid in your eye socket.

**A liquid keeps me from being slim.**

> Eye is kept big and round from liquid in the eye via osmosis

**Only few people can see my wave.**

> REM sleep? The eye does literally go up and down so is it waving?
>  People can see if they open your eye while you are asleep or by using
>  some kind of a scanner. Also REM is often literally plotted as a
>  "wave" (sine wave, etc) on a graph.

**I spend my nights in a kind of cave.**

> You close your eye lids. Need I say more?

**I don’t breathe, yet cannot drown.**

> Eyes don't breathe, and are in liquid.

**When things get serious, I prefer upside-down.**

> The eye actually takes in light upside down and your brain corrects
>  it. So if you take serious as being awake and seeing, then everytime
>  your eye is open it is actually taking in everything upside down.
>  Sounds pretty serious to me.

**Conclusion:**

> I put forth the eye!

Comment: I'm impressed - that's pretty creative and all accurate! These kinds of answers are what make posting riddles on here fun!